# Indexing string in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out only the odd indexed characters of an input string. I can't use string slicing but instead must use a loop. How it this done? Here is my code:

```
string = input("Please enter a string: ")

for each_char in string:
    print("\n%s" % each_char)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

direct string indexing will also work:

```
string = input("Please enter a string: ")

for i in range(1, len(string), 2):
    print(string[i])
```

output:

```
Please enter a string: hello world
e
l

o
l
```

note the third (`step`) argument of [`range(start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#range).

and - yes - slicing would be much more elegant.

---

**update:** because you asked for it - here the version with slicing (you will find more information about slicing in the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html)):

```
for char in string[1::2]:
    print(char)
```

Comment: Though this is a perfectly valid answer, many pythonistas frown over the use of `range`. That probably explains the dv. :-)

Comment: thanks. i was wondering about that. but if slicing is forbidden the most pythonic code does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`enumerate` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
>>> string = input("Please enter a string: ")
Please enter a string: helloworld

>>> for k,v in enumerate(string):
...     if k%2==1:
...         print(v)  # No need \n as print automatically prints newline
... 
e
l
w
r
d
```