# Write a program that prompts for the user to input a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a program that prompts for the user to input a sentence. Then check this sentence to make sure the first word of the sentence is capitalized and the sentence ends with a punctuation mark. If it is not properly written, fix the sentence, print the type of error, and print the fixed sentence.

I was following the provided instructions for this class and keep getting an invalid syntax error for the fourth line of code. Was wondering if anyone knew why and could show me how to fix it or another way of writing this program.

```
import string

sentence = input("Enter a sentence ")

class acceptSentence():

    punctuationcount = lambda a,b:len(list(filter(lambda c: c in b,a)))

    numberofpunctuationcount =  punctuationcount(sentence,string.punctuation)

for each in sentence:
    if each.startswith(each.upper()):
        print ("Starts with Capital letter ",each)

        break

    if (numberofpunctuations >=1):

        print("Sentence Ends with punctuation")

    else:
        print("Error : there is no punctuion mark at end of setence")


        obj = acceptSentence()
        obj.calculate(sentence)
```

Comment: `lamdba-c` is an invalid syntax.  Did you mean `lambda c:`?

Comment: Also the indentation is wrong, at least in this copy-pasted snippet

Comment: @Idlehands that's actually what it was originally I tried a few things to get it to work. it still shows the c as invalid syntax

Comment: @RunOrVeith it is correct in the actual code i just didnt check it when it was copied

Comment: If this is the actual snippet without any modification, besides the possible indentation issue, you haven't actually defined anything under `class acceptSentence()` so the interpreter is complaining.  Seeing as how you refer to `obj.calculate(sentence)` though I'm assuming you had some definition you just omitted? Because nowhere is `.calculate()` method referenced.

Comment: I correct some of the formatting issues, and I did fix the syntax issue now it does work but the output I am getting isn't matching the actual problem.

Comment: Then you will need to provide an example input, actual output and expected output.  Also as mentioned, `obj.calculate(sentence)` should give you an error since it's not defined.

Comment: Only the first word must start in uppercase. You are checking each word in the sentence.

Comment: This is my current output from python.

    Enter a sentence Hello.
    Starts with Capital letter  H
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Exercise 4-2.3.py", line 5, in <module>
    class acceptSentence(sentence):
    TypeError: str() argument 2 must be str, not tuple

Comment: You are overdoing it. Check my answer, it's much easier than what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence ").lstrip()  # remove trailing whitespaces

# check if first character is uppercase
if not sentence[0].isupper():
    print("Sentence does not start with uppercase character")
    # correct the sentence
    sentence = sentence[0].upper() + sentence[1:]

# check if last character is a punctuation 
# (feel free to add other punctuations)
if sentence[-1] not in (['.']):
    print("Sentence does not end with punctuation character")
    # correct the sentence
    sentence += '.'

#finally print the correct sentence
print(sentence)
```

Comment: This is actually a much simple way of writing the program thank you! I don't know why the instructions I was provided were incorrect. looking at them again the expected output doesn't actually print the fixed sentence so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description you may be overthinking the task: it speaks about a single sentence, and then you just have to make sure that the first letter is upper case and there is punctuation at the end:

```
def sentence():
  text=input("Please type a sentence here: ")

  if text[0].isalpha() and not text[0].isupper(): # Begins with letter, but not uppercase?
    text=text[0].upper()+text[1:]                 # Make it uppercase then
    print("Sentences should start in uppercase");

  if text[-1] not in [".","!","?"]:               # Does not end with punctuation?
    text+="."                                     # Append a period then
    print("Sentences should end with punctuation mark")

  return text
```

It can be both extended (like `.strip()`-ing whitespace, just add it to the `input`-line), or even shortened (the first `if` can be removed, since there is nothing wrong with calling `.upper()` on something what is uppercase already). However since the error has to be printed, the `if` has to stay in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not properly indented, which is what leads to an IndentationError when executing it. Your lambda filter also spits out a SyntaxError because of the incorrect spelling of "lambda". Your if-else statement is also misaligned, be careful how you indent your code.

Here's a simpler alternative to your program:

```
import string

sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")

first_word = sentence.split()[0] # .split() gives you a list of words in the sentence, 0 is the index of the first word;

capitalized_first_word = first_word.title() # .title() capitalizes a string;

# Check whether the first word is not equal to the capitalized word:
if first_word != capitalized_first_word:
    print ("Sentence does not start with a capital letter.")
    # Replace the first word in the sentence with the capitalized word:
    sentence = sentence.replace(first_word, capitalized_first_word)

# Check if the sentence does not end with a punctuation mark, -1 is the index of the last character in the sentence:
if not sentence[-1] in string.punctuation:
    print("Sentence does not end with punctuation.")
    # Add punctuation to the end of the sentence:
    sentence += '.'

# Print the sentence:
print(sentence)
```

Look into [string indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769025/indexing-string-in-python) for more details.